# Why does this box make a noise when I click on it?

Tags: portal-2

In the Cooperative Hub area near each of the chamber selection screens there is a small box that talks whenever you click on it. Aside from sounding like a turret, does the box have a purpose? These are the ones that light up purple as they are activated.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? It will help identifying the box without actually launching the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [this](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aesca/screenshot/541772629970413243?tab=public) the box you are talking about?
It has no practical use. It's there just for fun.

[image]